# Surface Energy Dependence on Temperature

Tags: temperature, surface-tension

Surface energy is an energy needed to increase surface area of the interphase by unit or excess energy molecules have on the surface compared to the bulk. This means that surface energy will depend on bond strength or energy for a given substance.

It is said that surface energy usually decreases with temperature. However, this doesn't make sense because ,as far as I know, bond energy doesn't depend on temperature. When we increase temperature, average molecular kinetic energy increases, but what does that have to do with bond energy?